# Flask how to redireect url_for

Tags: python, html, flask, yolov5

I want to redirect(url_for('product_page')) when obj_class == 0, but when obj_class == 0 is detected, an error will be displayed:** This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.**
But obj_class == 1 and 2 can be successfully detected and the link can be opened, please help.

And my product_page.html is also placed in the templates folder.

my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect, url_for
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import time
import webbrowser

app = Flask(__name__)

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt', force_reload=True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
height, width, _ = cap.read()[1].shape
baseline = height // 2 + 100

# 存儲已跳轉過的網頁
opened_links = []

video_paused = False  

detected_object_names = []  # 使用列表來存儲檢測到的物體名稱


def detect_objects():
    while cap.isOpened():
        
        
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
            continue
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 480))

        results = model(frame)
        detected_objects = results.xyxy[0]
        cv2.line(frame, (0, baseline), (width, baseline), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)
       
        for obj in detected_objects:
            obj_class = int(obj[-1])
            if obj_class in [0, 1, 2]:
                obj_center_x = (obj[0] + obj[2]) / 2 + 100
                obj_center_y = (obj[1] + obj[3]) / 2 + 100
                if obj_center_y > baseline:
                    link_url = ""
                    if obj_class == 0:
                        detected_object_name = "柚香" 
                        return redirect(url_for('product_page'))
                    elif obj_class == 1:
                        link_url = "https://online.carrefour.com.tw/zh/%E7%A6%8F%E6%A8%82/1502200500124.html"
                        detected_object_name = "福樂"  
                    elif obj_class == 2:
                        link_url = "https://ecshweb.pchome.com.tw/search/v3.3/?q=%E7%BE%8E%E7%A5%BF"
                        detected_object_name = "美祿"  

                    if link_url not in opened_links:
                        webbrowser.open(link_url)
                        opened_links.append(link_url)
                        detected_object_names.append(detected_object_name)
                        # 跳轉網頁後暫停 3 秒再繼續偵測
                        time.sleep(3)
                    break

        img_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', np.squeeze(results.render()))[1].tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img_bytes + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(detect_objects(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/start_video', methods=['POST'])
def start_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = False
    return '已啟動'


@app.route('/stop_video', methods=['POST'])  
def stop_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = True
    cap.release()  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  
    return '已停止'


@app.route('/pause_video', methods=['POST'])
def pause_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = True
    return '已暂停'


@app.route('/resume_video', methods=['POST'])
def resume_video():
    global video_paused
    video_paused = False
    return '已繼續'


@app.route('/other_page')
def other_page():
    return render_template('other_page.html', object_names=detected_object_names)

@app.route('/product_page')
def product_page():
    return render_template('product_page.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

my home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>哭哭</title>
    <style>
      .dialog-overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 9999;
      }

      .dialog-content {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        max-width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .dialog-buttons {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>人生好難</h1>
    <button onclick="startDetection()" type="button">開始掃描</button>
    <button onclick="pauseDetection()" type="button">暫停掃描</button>
    <button onclick="resumeDetection()" type="button">繼續掃描</button>
    <button onclick="openDialog()" type="button">掃描紀錄</button>
    <img id="videoStream" width="800" height="480">

    <div id="dialog" class="dialog-overlay" style="display: none;">
      <div class="dialog-content">
        <iframe id="dialogFrame" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        <button onclick="closeDialog()" type="button">關閉</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    
  
    
    
    <script>
      let videoStarted = false;

      function startDetection() {
        fetch('/start_video', {
          method: 'POST'
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('已啟動');
              videoStarted = true; // 设置videoStarted为true
              document.getElementById('videoStream').src = "{{ url_for('video_feed') }}";
            } else {
              console.log('無法啟動');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }

      function stopDetection() {
        fetch('/stop_video', {
          method: 'POST'
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('已停止');
              videoStarted = false; // 设置videoStarted为false
            } else {
              console.log('無法停止');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }

      function pauseDetection() {
        fetch('/pause_video', {
          method: 'POST'
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('已暫停');
              videoStarted = false; // 设置videoStarted为false
            } else {
              console.log('無法暫停');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }

      function resumeDetection() {
        fetch('/resume_video', {
          method: 'POST'
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log('已繼續');
              videoStarted = true; // 设置videoStarted为true
            } else {
              console.log('無法繼續');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }

      function openDialog() {
        document.getElementById('dialog').style.display = 'flex';
        document.getElementById('dialogFrame').src = "/other_page";
      }

      function closeDialog() {
        document.getElementById('dialog').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('dialogFrame').src = "";
      }

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
        if (videoStarted) {
          stopDetection();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring because in your code, you are returning the redirect() call directly from the detect_objects() function. In flask, you need to do it within the application context.

You can refactor to redirect from within a Flask route function.

- Remove the return redirect(url_for('product_page')) statement from the detect_objects() function.
- Modify the detected_objects loop in the detect_objects() function to store the detected object names in a list.

  ```
  for obj in detected_objects:
      detected_object_names.append(detected_object_name)
  ```
- Create a new route function, such as redirect_product_page(), which performs the redirection to the product page.

  ```
  @app.route('/redirect_product_page')
  def redirect_product_page():
      return redirect(url_for('product_page'))
  ```
- Update the logic inside the detect_objects() function to trigger the redirection to the product page.

  ```
  if obj_class == 0:
      detected_object_name = "柚香"
      return redirect(url_for('redirect_product_page'))
  ```

After these changes, when obj_class will be 0, the detect_objects() function will trigger a redirect to the redirect_product_page() route function, which in turn will redirect to the product_page() route function where the product_page.html template will be rendered.

Comment: After the modification, my program did not run out of detection, and it directly jumped to my product_page.html